# change tick labels of bar graph to logarithmic scale

Tags: matlab

I am a bit confused on how to draw a bar graph for the following example:

```
x_lims = [1000,10000;10000,100000;100000,1000000;1000000,10000000;10000000,...
    100000000;100000000,1000000000;1000000000,10000000000;...
    10000000000,100000000000;100000000000,1e12]; 
ex1 = [277422033.049038;24118536.4203188;2096819.03295482;...
    182293.402068030;15905;1330;105;16;1];
```

Here, x_lims is the x axis limits for each individual bar and ex1 is the count. How can I plot these on a bar graph so that the width of each individual bar along the x axis is defined by the distance between x_lims(:,1) and x_lims(:,2) and the y value is defined by ex1?

So far I have:

```
bar(log10(x_lims(:,1)),log10(ex1));
set(gca,'Xtick',3:11,'YTick',0:9);
set(gca,'Xticklabel',10.^get(gca,'Xtick'),...
    'Yticklabel',10.^get(gca,'Ytick'));
```

[image]

But I would like to (1) have the labels to be the same as if they were created using semilogx or semilogy e.g. 10^9, and (2) I would like to remove the space between the bars, for the first bar, for example, I would like to have it extend horizontally from 1000 to 10000 and then the second bar from 10000 to 100000, and so on. How can this be done?

Just realised I can use

```
'BarWidth', 1
```

to define the width of the bars.

So, how to change the labels to 10^, and make the bars extend over the valkues in x_lims and not in the middle of the tick (if that makes sense)

Comment: If you want to change the x-axis check `set(gca, 'XTick',mytest_x_axis, 'XTickLabel',mytest_timeline)` Here `my_test_x_axis` is the x-axis e.g. 1:10 and `my_test_timeline` a timeline with 10 elements I wanted to have as new x-Axis. FOr the log-scale use `histc()` to compute the counts in each bin. Then compute the log and then use `bar()` to plot the new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines. Credit goes to @Dan for the `arrayfun` part.

```
bar(log10(x_lims(:,1)),log10(ex1),'BarWidth',1);
labelsx = arrayfun(@(x)(['10^', num2str(x)]), log10(unique(x_lims(:))), ...
   'UniformOutput', false);
labelsy = arrayfun(@(x)(['10^', num2str(x)]), get(gca,'ytick'), ...
   'UniformOutput', false);
set(gca,'Xtick',2.5:11.5,'YTick',0:9);
set(gca,'Xticklabel',labelsx,'Yticklabel',labelsy);
set(gca,'TickDir', 'out') %// make ticks visible
set(gca,'Fontsize', 8) %// "separate" labels
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
labels = arrayfun(@(x)(['10^', num2str(x)]), get(gca,'Xtick'), 'UniformOutput', false)
set(gca,'Xticklabel',labels,...
    'Yticklabel',10.^get(gca,'Ytick'));
```

Comment: +1. I've borrowed the `arrayfun` idea for my answer (with due credit). I hope you don't mind